# Oшибкa: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'

Tags: python, scapy

Scapy:

```
pkt.getlayer(ARP).op
```

вызывает ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'

---

```
import time
from scapy.all import *
import netsyslog
import syslog

arp_table = {}
def arp_inspection(pkt):
    global arp_table
    op = pkt.getlayer(ARP).op
    src = pkt.getlayer(Ether).src
    if op == 1:
        arp_table[src] = time.time()
    if op == 2:
        dst = pkt.getlayer(Ether).dst 
        if dst in arp_table:
            time_arp_req = arp_table.pop(dst, None)
def send_syslog():
    loggers = netsyslog.Logger()
    loggers.add_host("192.168.1.247")
    loggers.log(syslog.LOG_USER, syslog.LOG_NOTICE, "Alert! Attack from %s" % src, pid=True)
send_syslog()
sniff(filter='arp', prn=arp_inspection)
```

На что мне выдает

> ```
> File "sys.py", line 22, in <module>
> sniff(filter='arp', prn=arp_inspection) 
>  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 
>  780, in sniff
>  r = prn(p)
>  File "sys.py", line 9, in arp_inspection
>  op = pkt.getlayer(ARP).op
>  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'
> ```

Comment: Непонятен текст ошибки или какая проблема?

Comment: Собственно не понятно почему ошибка в этом месте. Ну и сама проблема если честно. Я новичок в Python и в scapy. Захотелось автоматизировать процесс определения арп-спуфинга с отправкой уведомления на удаленный syslog. Код частично взял с хабра.

Comment: в сторону: не используйте имена модулей, которые конфликтуют со стандартной библиотекой. Переименуйте `sys.py`¶ `global arp_table` не нужен здесь¶  Можно добавить сверху: `if not pkt.haslayer(ARP): return`. После этого можно `pkt[ARP].op` попробовать.